# Entity Framework validation error - Each property name in a type must be unique

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to map entities to an existing database using the Fluent API (EF6). Whenever I try to run the application, I get the following error:

```
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

FooId: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'FooId' is already defined.
FooId: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'FooId' is already defined.
BarId: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'BarId' is already defined.
```

Following is a simplified view of the problematic area in the database. So we have a Bar entity, which is related to one or more Foo instances. Each Foo may be related to a MoreFoo and each MoreFoo may be related to multiple EvenMoreFoo instances.

[image]

Note that the EvenMoreFoo entity has a composite primary key! Also note that in order to link a MoreFoo to a Foo, the equivalence MoreFoo.FooId = Foo.FooId needs to be true. Same for linking EvenMoreFoo's to a MoreFoo.

The relation mapping using the Fluent API look like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
            .HasOptional(x => x.Bar)
            .WithMany(x => x.Foos)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.BarId);

modelBuilder.Entity<MoreFoo>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.Foo)
            .WithOptional(x => x.MoreFoo)
            .Map(x => x.MapKey("FooId"));

modelBuilder.Entity<MoreFoo>()
            .HasMany(x => x.EvenMoreFoos)
            .WithRequired(x => x.MoreFoo)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.FooId);

modelBuilder.Entity<EvenMoreFoo>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.MoreFoo)
            .WithMany(x => x.EvenMoreFoos)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.FooId);
```

I have no clue why the error is being thrown. No entity has the same property name defined twice, so it has something to do with the way the relations are mapped using the Fluent API. Is it the fact that the key FooId is used on multiple entities? I would be thankful if someone is able to tell me the mistake I am making.

### Edit

After some more toying around, I have come to the conclusion that the error is in the following mapping (more specific: the last line of it):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MoreFoo>()
        .HasRequired(x => x.Foo)
        .WithOptional(x => x.MoreFoo)
        .Map(x => x.MapKey("FooId"));
```

In the whole codebase such a thing is done three times: twice for `FooId` and once for `BarId`. This corresponds with the error. Still trying to figure out how to fix it though.

Comment: Maybe you can try removing mappings one by one to see which one causes the error.

Comment: I have been able to pinpoint the mapping that is causing some trouble. It has something to do with the one-on-one relation that has its foreign key specified as a string.

Comment: Does MoreFoo have a PK?

Comment: Yes, its primary key is `FooId`, which is apparently also a foreign key to `Foo`.

Comment: And where is the error thrown? Here: ".Map(x => x.MapKey("FooId"));" ?

Comment: It is being thrown when trying to update and save a Bar to the database when `SaveChanges()` is called.

Comment: Updated the answer. Can you look a bit over models if they match yours and if they do try the proposed solution?

Answer (score 1):

For this code snippet, it performs ok:

```
public class Foo {
    public int FoodId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MoreFoo> MoreFoo { get; set; }
    public int BarId { get; set; }
}

public class MoreFoo {
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public Foo Foo { get; set; }
    public string SomeAttr { get; set; }
}

var modelBuilder = new DbModelBuilder();

modelBuilder.Entity<MoreFoo>()
                .HasRequired(x => x.Foo)
                .WithMany(x => x.MoreFoo)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.FooId);
```

Comment: In your example, `Foo` is related to multiple `MoreFoo` instances. However, the attribute `MoreFoo.FooId` is a primary and a foreign key at the same time. Thus, a `Foo` can have at most one `MoreFoo` (as `MoreFoo.FooId` is a foreign key to `Foo`).

Comment: I'm still confused how it can be a PK and FK at the same time. Why don't you name your FK somehow else? The PK as one column, the FK as a separate column in the table/class.

Comment: Unfortunately, the database scheme was supplied to me. I can't change it on the fly.

Comment: Tried to apply your solution. Now the following error pops up:

`One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

MoreFoo_Foo_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'MoreFoo_Foo_Source' in relationship 'MoreFoo_Foo'. Because the Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '1'.`